# Make no item selected in windows phone toolkit list picker

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using the ListPicker control from the WP7 Toolkit. I want to initially present the list with no items selected. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx) List Picker works with the idea of "there is always an active selection".

The approach I would follow is to have the first item in the list be you "no selected item" item. With appropriate values (maybe a null id) that you can identify later on.

Comment: I'm currently using a "Please select an item..." first item but it's not ideal. It becomes a selectable item on the popup list. Will try collapsed first item solution and keep this as a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

By design ListPicker must have a selected item. If you try to set it to null or set the SelectedIndex to -1 you will get an exception.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'm binding an observable collection via a view model so will have to figure out how to collapse the first item. My list picker is in a user control so may be able to do it an event.

Comment: How do I cast my observable collection item to a ListPickerItem?

Comment: You can get the first item in this way: ListPickerItem firstItem = this.list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListPickerItem;

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to get a container out of the generator. I can see items in there but I get a null object out?

Comment: Managed now - had to do it in LayoutUpdated event. Doesn't work - if I collapse the first item, the second is selected.