# Changing ItemsSource property correctly (Windows Phone - MVVM)

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I am building a Windows Phone 8 application (using MVVM Light) where I have a listpicker whose ItemsSource (one-way) & SelectedItem (two-way) are both bound to properties on a single ViewModel. Now, my question is: what is the recommended way to update the ItemsSource to a completely different set of items (that probably won't overlap with the old)?

Just replacing it, or its contents, doesn't work as I get errors because the SelectedItem is not valid. Obviously if I set the SelectedItem first, I get an error because the item isn't in the source collection yet. I've seen some workarounds that were either messy or too verbose, but I think there must already exist an easier solution since this seems to be a very common pattern.

Comment: Share what you have tried and what errors you got, to know the solution for your question. Else, no one can able to answer.

Comment: My best solution so far was in the getter of the SelectedItem backing property add a check that if it is not contained in the collection, set it to the first element of the collection. However, that still feels a bit like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `SelectedItem` to null before you clear your `ObservableCollection<T>` and re-add items to it.

Be sure that the type of the `SelectedItem` property is `nullable`.

Comment: References are always nullable, but how can I make it accept the "null" value without breaking?
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938439/make-no-item-selected-in-windows-phone-toolkit-list-picker)