# Toolkit list picker item is selected by default

Tags: windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8.I have to select single item  from list .I can use toolkit list picker .But the issue is default value is selected as first one. It should be empty i.e by default no item is selected

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938439/make-no-item-selected-in-windows-phone-toolkit-list-picker), there is also [a link to this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx), where you can find some useful information.

Answer (score 2):

simply add a item named "please select" and set it as default. If the user doesn't select a item you can check if this item is stil selected and prevent the user from the next step.

you can think of the listpicker like a dropdown menu in html. there is no way a dropdown box is in a state where no item is selected.

Comment: I am not manually giving the data binding data coming from  services

Comment: don't bind the data directly from a service. fetch it from your service and manage the states in your own Enuberable Object. (eg. within your viewModel or CodeBehind) that way you stay in control of the items.